# Kinect model 1520 connected to mac

Tags: macos, kinect

I have a Kinect for XBox One, model 1520. On my MacBook Pro running 10.10.5, I installed freenect and am attempting to run freenect-glview. I am getting the error:

```
Kinect camera test
Number of devices found: 0
```

When I look in the USB device tree, I can see USB 3.0 SuperSpeed bus > NUI Sensor Adapter > XBox NUI sensor. I also see another NUI Sensor Adapter under USB 3.0 Hi-Speed Bus.

Comment: freenect-glview? Sounds like you are using libfreenect 1. For the Kinect for XBox One (often called Kinect v2), you have to use libfreenect2, which you have to build yourself: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2

Comment: I see an example of someone using the 1520 with libfreenect 1 here: https://github.com/shiffman/OpenKinect-for-Processing/issues/25

Comment: I see. I'm not familiar with that wrapper, so I won't be able to help. But it does use libfreenect2 for the Kinect for XBox One.